# Setting up a SDN environment

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am setting up a SDN network with :

- a VM with the SDN controller (Ryu)
- a VM with Openvswitch
- 2 VMs for hosts linked to the switch.

I am using VirtualBox and I put the controller and the switch into the same network (internal network intnet). This works, I see that they can communicate.

Now I want to bridge the two hosts to the switch. I created a bridge br0 on the switch and two virtual interfaces vport1 and vport2. But when I access VirtualBox on my physical machine, I cannot choose "Bridge adapter -> vport1" for my host1 as I created vport1 on the switch VM.

Any suggestion?